# How can one prove the worst case scenario of an algorithm purely mathematically?

Tags: proof-writing, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

How can someone prove purely mathematically that the worst case scenario (Big O) of the number of iteration of a recursive search algorithm is, let's say, 2 * log3(n)?

The only method that comes in my mind is by trying all possible combinations of a somewhat small list of elements (for example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), recording the time it takes, and find the worse time. Then, I would repeat it with a couple of different lists, then find, within the classical functions range (n^2, n^3, log(n), n*log(n), etc.) the most similar function according to the worse data points (worse time for each list).

Is it possible to prove any similar algorithm purely mathematically and not programmatically? What would be the steps for it?

Answer (score 1):

Proving worst case complexity depends upon the particular algorithm, of course, but a general approach is to examine each branch of the algorithm and assume the ("worst case") data always happens to demand the longest (most complex) branch at each decision.  You needn't test *all* possible orders of data for such an analysis.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me an example with any sort algorithm you want?

Comment: BubbleSort, QuickSort, etc...

Comment: No I meant, could you pick any algorithm you want and make a small proof of the worse case scenario? Doesn't matter if the algorithm is simple, like binary sort, seeing a valid proof would really help me getting started.

Comment: Your question did not involve *my* proving for you a special case... and I will not do so.